# Why does my Selenium script only work some of the time?

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, safaridriver

I am having one of the weirdest problems ever.

My script below works about 50% of the time, the other time it doesn't make it passed the first button click.

```
browser = webdriver.Safari()
browser.get('https://www.onvista.de/')
WebDriverWait(browser, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "Ich stimme zu")))
confirmation = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='Ich stimme zu']")
confirmation.click()
time.sleep(5)
search_bar = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='searchValue']")
search_bar.send_keys('A2H89T')
search_bar.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.LINK_TEXT, "T&S/Historie")))
history = browser.find_element_by_link_text("T&S/Historie")
history.click()
onvista_url = browser.current_url

onvista_html = requests.get(onvista_url).text
onvista_page = BeautifulSoup(onvista_html, 'lxml')

print(onvista_page)
```

I've checked the source code and three error messages appear:

1. Failed to preconnect to https://geo.smartadserver.mgr.consensu.org/. Error: The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be “geo.smartadserver.mgr.consensu.org”, which could put your confidential information at risk.
2. ReferenceError: Can't find variable: sas
   Global Code — www.onvista.de:632
   defaultOnError — libs-73265.js:1:930
3. [Error] Error: Script error for "conversion_async"
   http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
   defaultOnError (libs-73265.js:1:930)
   s (libs-73265.js:1:3280)
   onScriptError (libs-73265.js:1:13263)

What is particularly strange is that Python does not display an error message, the script just doesn't do anything once the webpage has been loaded.

Can anyone explain what is going wrong? Why does it sometimes work, and sometimes not?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This sounds like an [X-Y problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Instead of asking for help with your solution to the problem, edit your question and ask about the actual problem. What are you trying to do?